# Rails Production Container "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

Using the Rails 6 "Blog" template guide, successfully created and ran Rails app in Development on Ubuntu 20.04.

Using this guide https://blog.engineyard.com/using-docker-for-rails, I created the production container (I needed to extend the dummy database string with a dummer key master for precomile in Rails 6). The resulting container starts but the page of smiling Rails faces (Yay! You’re on Rails!) does not appear, instead.

[image: landing page, root context]

Note: I have read several different page opinions on Rails in Production container and they have the same basic process as the page referenced, with suble variations on environment variable placement, etc. The log from the container follows

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.3.3 application starting in production 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.6 (ruby 2.7.0-p0), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: production
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
I, [2020-09-26T22:29:36.819615 #1]  INFO -- : [272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] Started GET "/" for 172.23.0.3 at 2020-09-26 22:29:36 +0000
F, [2020-09-26T22:29:36.820134 #1] FATAL -- : [272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211]   
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211]   
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] actionpack (6.0.3.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:36:in `call'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] actionpack (6.0.3.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] railties (6.0.3.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] railties (6.0.3.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] activesupport (6.0.3.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] activesupport (6.0.3.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] activesupport (6.0.3.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] railties (6.0.3.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] actionpack (6.0.3.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] actionpack (6.0.3.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] activesupport (6.0.3.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] actionpack (6.0.3.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] actionpack (6.0.3.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] actionpack (6.0.3.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:82:in `call'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] railties (6.0.3.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] puma (4.3.6) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] puma (4.3.6) lib/puma/server.rb:713:in `handle_request'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] puma (4.3.6) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] puma (4.3.6) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
[272cb1aa-9a2a-43f9-bf40-66d4b9a43211] puma (4.3.6) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I have verified the static content is presenting by testing /robots.txt and this downloads as expected.

Comment: Could you show routes?

Comment: It was my woeful lack of Rails understanding that was the problem. I wanted to get a "vanilla" instance into production to make a clean start for the development process, however the archetype smoke-test route only works in Development.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, the following smoke-test image only renders in development

[image: development smoketest]

I progressed one more step on the tutorial, with the key being a genuine route and once installed in the production container, it rendered the same as Development.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
 
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

I can now start my development journey.